# Reduce returns unpredictable results for parallel stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I have wrote the following code sample with java stream reduce:

```
Person reducedPerson = Person.getPersons().stream()
                .parallel()  //will return surprising result
                .reduce(new Person(), (intermediateResult, p2) -> {
                            intermediateResult.setAge(intermediateResult.getAge() + p2.getAge());
                            return intermediateResult;
                        },
                        (ir1, ir2) -> {
                            ir1.setAge(ir1.getAge() + ir2.getAge());
                            return ir1;
                        });
        System.out.println(reducedPerson);
```

model:

```
public class Person {

    String name;

    Integer age;

    public Person() {
        age = 0;
        name = "default";
    }

    //...
    public Person(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static Collection<Person> getPersons() {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Vasya", 12));
        persons.add(new Person("Petya", 32));
        persons.add(new Person("Serj", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("Onotole", 18));
        return persons;
    }
}
```

Each code sample execution returns different result:

example:
`Person{name='default', age=256}`
or

```
Person{name='default', age=248}
```

I have loclized that problem inside `combiner` because in sequental stream code executes correctly.

Please help to correct combiner.

P.S.

expected result: person with name 'default' and age 72(sum ges of all pepsons in list)

### P.S.

same code for Integer as reduce result works properly:

```
Integer age = Person.getPersons().stream()
                .parallel()
                .reduce(0, (intermediateResult, p2) -> {
                    intermediateResult = intermediateResult + p2.getAge();
                    return intermediateResult;
                }, (ir1, ir2) -> {
                    System.out.println("combiner");
                    ir1 = ir1 + ir2;
                    return ir1;
                });
        System.out.println(age);
```

Comment: That's because your `reduce` call violates all possible parts of the contract. Please read the documentation. You should never mutate objects in the stream.

Comment: @Boris the Spider As I understood in combiner I should merge 2 intermediate results and return merge result

Comment: Yes. It should. You don't combine, you mutate one of the objects then return it.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using the three-argument version of `reduce` instead of the two-argument, since the accumulator is the same type as your inputs.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I want to use parallel stream

Comment: @Louis Wasserman if to remove third argument - it doesn't work predictable too

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, that's an independent issue, but you should do it anyway.  That said, why not write the more logical, efficient, and straightforward `Person.getPersons().stream().parallel().mapToInt(Person::getAge).sum()` ?  Why do you need to produce a `Person` instead of a summed age, which would be more logical?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I just want to understand tool

Comment: Are you calling it more than once in the same program?  Or are you just running the whole program over again and getting different results?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman second option

Comment: Then I strongly suspect your `reduce` implementation is actually modifying the objects stored in the `Persons` collection in different ways.  This is part of _why_ you don't modify objects in stream operations, because of these unpredictable effects.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I want to modify only one **new Person()** which I pass as first argument

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it.  You're modifying the _identity_, and the same identity object is getting reused multiple times.  More or less, you can't do that with `reduce`; you'll have to produce new `Person` objects each time instead of modifying one of them.

Comment: That's your issue: you can't modify the identity object when it's getting merged in several different groups, which is the case when you use parallelism.  `collect` will let you modify the accumulator, because it supplies a new identity for every group of objects being combined; `reduce` cannot modify the identity object.

Comment: Can you help me to write what I want?

Comment: @Boris the Spider I mutate only intermediate result

Comment: @gstackoverflow in a `reduce` operation all items are assumed to be **immutable**. An operation takes two **immutable** items and generates a third - like summing two ints. If you have a **mutable** container you must use [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) which is designed to work with a mutable container.

Comment: @Boris the Spider hmm... looks like I begin understand why there exists 2 methods( reduce and collect) reduce for immutable containers and collet for mutable.

Comment: @gstackoverflow, in your later PS you are not mutating objects. You simply cannot: `Integer`'s are immutable. You just assign a parameter to a new `Integer` object. Method local variables and parameters are your property, you can do with them everything you like and nobody else will notice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To perform mutable reduction, use `collect`:

```
reducedPerson = Person.getPersons().parallelStream()
        .collect(
                Person::new,
                (p, q) -> p.setAge(p.getAge() + q.getAge()),
                (p, q) -> p.setAge(p.getAge() + q.getAge())
        );
```

`collect` is specifically designed to accumulate into mutable containers safely even in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

As Boris noted, the problem is mutation within a stream.

> Most stream operations accept parameters that describe user-specified
>   behavior, such as the lambda expression w -> w.getWeight() passed to
>   mapToInt in the example above. To preserve correct behavior, these
>   behavioral parameters:
>
> - must be non-interfering (they do not modify the stream source); and in
> - most cases must be stateless (their result should not depend on any
>     state that might change during execution of the stream pipeline).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Here is version using reduce, and the more straightforward version using maptoint and sum.

```
class gstackoverflow{
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Person reducedPerson = Person.getPersons().stream()
        .parallel()  //will NOT return surprising result
        .reduce(new Person("default",0),
            (ir1, ir2) -> //no longer mutates
                new Person(String.join(",", ir1.getName(), ir2.getName()), ir1.getAge() + ir2.getAge())
        );
    System.out.println(reducedPerson);

    //here is a clean(er) way to do it:
    int totalAge = Person.getPersons().stream()
        .parallel()  //will NOT return surprising result
        .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
        .sum();
    System.out.println(totalAge);
  }
}

class Person {//no longer mutable

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  final String name;

  final Integer age;

  //no args constructor removed
  public Person(String name, Integer age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public static Collection<Person> getPersons() {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Vasya", 12));
    persons.add(new Person("Petya", 32));
    persons.add(new Person("Serj", 10));
    persons.add(new Person("Onotole", 18));
    return persons;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Person{");
    sb.append("name='").append(name).append('\'');
    sb.append(", age=").append(age);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```